# Pass cut string into environment variable?

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0

I'm trying to cut my git tag and pass this as an environment variable so other parts of my circle ci build know which directory to look at. How do I go about doing this?

```
  run-terraform:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/python:3.8.6-node
    environment:
      DEPLOY_STAGE: <<pipeline.git.tag>> | cut -f1 -d'/'
```

```
some-step:
    steps:
      - run:
          name: "Do thing."
          command: |
            do thing --arg $DEPLOY_STAGE-rest-of-string
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is not possible.

But what you could do is implement a ["setup workflow"](https://circleci.com/docs/dynamic-config) to set the value of a pipeline parameter declared in the "continuation" workflow.